# Will UbuntuTouch run on the Nexus 5 device?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

Now, you can see my question above.
Will Ubuntu Touch run on the Nexus 5 device. And/Or will Canonical support the Nexus 5 device?

Because I will buy a Nexus 5 and I would like to use Ubuntu Touch on it.

Greetz and thanks.

Ralf Lange